# How to read a single character from input as u8?

Tags: input, rust, stdin

I am currently building a simple interpreter for [this language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) for practice. The only problem left to overcome is reading a single byte as a character from user input. I have the following code so far, but I need a way to turn the `String` that the second lines makes into a `u8` or another integer that I can cast:

```
let input = String::new()
let string = std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).ok().expect("Failed to read line");
let bytes = string.chars().nth(0) // Turn this to byte?
```

The value in bytes should be a `u8` which I can cast to a `i32` to use elsewhere. Perhaps there is a simpler way to do this, otherwise I will use any solution that works.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Reading just a byte and casting it to `i32`:

```
use std::io::Read;

let input: Option<i32> = std::io::stdin()
    .bytes() 
    .next()
    .and_then(|result| result.ok())
    .map(|byte| byte as i32);

println!("{:?}", input);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using .bytes() on the string and having problems, but it turns out I was using it wrong. This is working for me, I just have to unwrap it.

Comment: This seems to require Enter to be pushed before it grabs the byte.

Comment: @AndyHayden stdin is typically line buffered.Use [stdbuf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe) to change it.

Answer (score 3):

First, make your input mutable, then use `bytes()` instead of `chars()`.

```
let mut input = String::new();
let string = std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).ok().expect("Failed to read line");
let bytes = input.bytes().nth(0).expect("no byte read");
```

Please note that Rust strings are a sequence of UTF-8 codepoints, which are not necessarily byte-sized. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, using a `char` may be the better option.

Comment: I tried this, but it says it needs an i32. I used .collect() on the .bytes() but still no luck.

Comment: I think it's more idiomatic to use `next()` instead of `nth(0)`. Though they are exactly the same thing.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Agreed, I had changed the code given in the answer just enough to make it work (And I forgot the `as i32` cast. Damn).