# Rust: Ownership problem when trying to get next byte from Stdin

Tags: rust, stdin, ownership

I was modifing [a code snippet from github](https://github.com/kenkoooo/competitive-programming-rs/blob/master/src/utils/scanner.rs) which enable fast i/o in Rust for competitive-programming.

I want to add a feature making it can read single character from stdin, just like `getchar` in C. My approach was a combination of the `pub fn read<T: std::str::FromStr>` in the original code snippet and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30679861/11017374)

```rust
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// https://github.com/kenkoooo/competitive-programming-rs/blob/master/src/utils/scanner.rs
/// let (stdin, stdout) = (std::io::stdin(), std::io::stdout());
/// let mut sc = IO::new(stdin.lock(), stdout.lock());
pub struct IO<R, W: std::io::Write>(R, std::io::BufWriter<W>);

impl<R: std::io::Read, W: std::io::Write> IO<R, W> {
    pub fn new(r: R, w: W) -> IO<R, W> {
        IO(r, std::io::BufWriter::new(w))
    }
    pub fn write<S: ToString>(&mut self, s: S) {
        use std::io::Write;
        self.1.write_all(s.to_string().as_bytes()).unwrap();
    }
    pub fn read<T: std::str::FromStr>(&mut self) -> T {
        use std::io::Read;
        let buf = self
            .0
            .by_ref()
            .bytes()
            .map(|b| b.unwrap())
            .skip_while(|&b| b == b' ' || b == b'\n' || b == b'\r' || b == b'\t')
            .take_while(|&b| b != b' ' && b != b'\n' && b != b'\r' && b != b'\t')
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        unsafe { std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&buf) }
            .parse()
            .ok()
            .expect("Parse error.")
    }
    pub fn usize0(&mut self) -> usize {
        self.read::<usize>() - 1
    }
    pub fn vec<T: std::str::FromStr>(&mut self, n: usize) -> Vec<T> {
        (0..n).map(|_| self.read()).collect()
    }
    pub fn chars(&mut self) -> Vec<char> {
        self.read::<String>().chars().collect()
    }
    pub fn char(&mut self) -> char {
        self
        .0
        .by_ref()
        .bytes()
        .next()
        .unwrap()
        .unwrap() as char
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#[allow(non_snake_case)]

fn main() {
    let (stdin, stdout) = (std::io::stdin(), std::io::stdout());
    let mut sc = IO::new(stdin.lock(), stdout.lock());

    let c = sc.char();
    sc.write(c);
}
```

`cargo run` and the output was:

```rust
$ cargo run
warning: unused manifest key: package.author
   Compiling ralgo v0.1.0 (/home/xxx/ralgo)
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a mutable reference
   --> src/main.rs:40:9
    |
40  | /         self
41  | |         .0
42  | |         .by_ref()
43  | |         .bytes()
    | |          ------^
    | |__________|_____|
    |            |     move occurs because value has type `R`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |            value moved due to this method call
    |
note: `bytes` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves value
   --> /home/xxx/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:922:14
    |
922 |     fn bytes(self) -> Bytes<Self>
    |              ^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: could not compile `ralgo` due to previous error
```

My questions:

1. The reason for this error and how to fix it.
2. Is there any better way to achieve `getchar` in Rust?
3. Why the rust-analyser shows the return type of `let buf = self.0.by_ref().bytes()` in the original `read` function is `Bytes<&mut R>` but for my code `self.0.by_ref().bytes()` it was `Bytes<R>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upfront, I want to note that your `read` is unsound. And furthermore the cost of allocating a vector is almost certainly going to dwarf the cost of validating that said vector is UTF8, so it's rather unnecessary.

> The reason for this error and how to fix it.

Because you don't `use std::io::Read` globally, the compiler knows that `R` specifically implements `Read` (as that's a bound), it does not know about any other implementation of `Read`. Notably, it does not know about `impl<R: Read + ?Sized> Read for &mut R`. Thus as far as it is concerned, the closest thing which would have a `bytes` method is the original reader, which it tries to deref'. The error is much clearer if you assign the result of `by_ref` to a local variable.

Just stop using fully qualified path like this, especially for traits. Your code is strictly less readable than if you just imported `Read`, `Write`, and `BufWriter` at the top.

> Is there any better way to achieve getchar in Rust?

getchar is a horrible function so I'm not too clear on why you'd want that. But I would suggest just using byteorder's [`read_u8`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/latest/byteorder/trait.ReadBytesExt.html#method.read_u8).

> Why the rust-analyser shows the return type

Possibly because it's getting confused and assumes all the traits are in scope.

> ```
>         .skip_while(|&b| b == b' ' || b == b'\n' || b == b'\r' || b == b'\t')
>         .take_while(|&b| b != b' ' && b != b'\n' && b != b'\r' && b != b'\t')
> ```

These seem like complicated ways of not calling [`u8::is_ascii_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u8.html#method.is_ascii_whitespace).

Comment: >Notably, it does not know about impl<R: Read + ?Sized> Read for &mut R. 

How is this known and how do you debug such errors?
Can you elaborate more about this? Thanks!

Comment: "How is this known" because it doesn't work. Same as not being able to call a method because the constraints of its `impl` block are not fulfilled. "how do you debug such errors? " habit I guess?